# Upload excel sheet on sharepoint having power query

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I have excel sheet with several power query queries. I want to share the results of those queries with other users on sharepoint. Those users might not have power query installed on their excels. What is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing more about what you're working with, here are some broad answers depending on your situation:

1. Users to View only - Other users should be able to *view* the sheet in the browser as long as it resides on a SharePoint site somewhere, and they have appropriate permissions to the site and document.
2. Users have client version of Excel but not PowerQuery - If the other users have Excel they can get the PowerQuery add-in for free and open the sheet there. Easily installed add-on through Excel, you can search for how to do this.
3. Users to edit, online only - Setup the SharePoint instance to open using Excel Services (as opposed to a WapiFrame). You'll have to work with a system admin to make that happen. Users will be able to open and edit the document with PowerQuery and PowerPivot features. At least this is how to do it in SharePoint2013. 2010 probably isn't much different.

Of course, for any of these options your workbook needs to be on a SharePoint site already and your users will need the appropriate permissions to access the site and document.

It would be helpful to know more details about the environment you are working in (SharePoint 2010? If it's 2013 is it OnPrem or Cloud? What level of access do you have to manipulate the environment? etc)